# What does a BRC mean in PL/SQL

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I trying am new to PL/SQL and am trying to learn it. Can anyone please tell me what does a BRC mean? How is it different from a stored procedure or a function?
What is the full form of it and how can I create a BRC? I was not able to find anything online.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've been dealing with Oracle longer than quarter of a century, and I still have a lot to learn. One of things I'm unfamiliar with is that **BRC** thing. What is it? Google doesn't know.

Comment: I don't think there is any such thing. Where did you come across it? Is it related to [PL/SQL Developer](https://www.allroundautomations.com/products/pl-sql-developer/) somehow?

Comment: Hi All, Sorry, it was related to my project and I thought that its a PL/SQL concept. Apologies.

Comment: For the curious among us, can you at least fill is in on what "BRC" stands for?